# Python Resource Manager Client to Azure China point to wrong endpoint

Tags: python, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy resources to Azure China with ARM Templates. I had the code to do it for Azure, and now I am adapting it for Azure China, I believe that the only changes that I should perform were in
Change the authority host in the credentials

```
self.credentials = DefaultAzureCredential(authority = AzureAuthorityHosts.AZURE_CHINA)
```

Change the Management Url in the Client.

```
endpoints = get_cloud_from_metadata_endpoint(os.environ.get("ARM_ENDPOINT"))
self.client = ResourceManagementClient(self.credentials, self.subscriptionId, base_url=endpoints.endpoints.resource_manager)
```

---

Below is the code that I am using
**Python Code:**

```
def __init__(self, subscriptionId, resourceGroup):
    self.logger = Logger("Azure China Connection")
    self.logger.info("Retrieving the list of available endpoint")
    # ARM_ENDPOINT = https://management.chinacloudapi.cn
    endpoints = get_cloud_from_metadata_endpoint(os.environ.get("ARM_ENDPOINT"))
    self.subscriptionId = subscriptionId
    self.resourceGroup = resourceGroup
    self.credentials = DefaultAzureCredential(authority = AzureAuthorityHosts.AZURE_CHINA)
    self.logger.info("Creating a client for deploying resources on subscription {}".format(self.subscriptionId))
    self.client = ResourceManagementClient(self.credentials, self.subscriptionId,
        # endpoints.endpoints.resource_manager = https://management.chinacloudapi.cn
        base_url=endpoints.endpoints.resource_manager)
    self.logger.success("Client was successfully created")
def deploy(self, template, parameters):
    resources = ""
    for resource in template.get("resources"):
        resources += "\n\t {}".format(resource.get("type"))
    self.logger.info("The following resources: {}\nwill be deployed".format(resources))
    deploymentProperties = DeploymentProperties(
        mode = DeploymentMode.incremental,
        template = template,
        parameters = parameters.get("parameters")
    )
    self.logger.info("Attempting deploy operation")
    deployment = self.client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
        self.resourceGroup,
        uuid7(),
        Deployment(properties=deploymentProperties)
    ) # Error occurs here
    self.logger.success("Resources deployment successfully triggered")
    return deployment.result()
load_dotenv()
connection = new AzureChinaConnection(os.environ.get("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"), os.environ.get("AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP"))
deployment = self.connection.deploy(template.json(), parameter.json())
```

> **Message=**DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the
> included credentials. **Attempted credentials:**  **EnvironmentCredential:**
> **Authentication failed:** **AADSTS500011:** The resource principal named
> ***https://management.azure.com*** was not found in the tenant named EY
> CHINA. This can happen if the application has not been installed by
> the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the
> tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong
> tenant. **Trace ID:** ace63d66-af4b-4457-b6c9-6ce050e34700 **Correlation ID:**
> d85942a5-35fb-493f-8eef-ee9fe1f64b7f **Timestamp:** 2022-09-29 19:44:47Z
> To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines
> here at
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot.

Based on the error message, it looks like I am pointing to a wrong endpoint ***https://management.azure.com*** instead of ***https://management.chinacloudapi.cn***. The question is, where should I set it?
I though that it was already doing it in the __init__

```
self.client = ResourceManagementClient(self.credentials, self.subscriptionId,
    # endpoints.endpoints.resource_manager = https://management.chinacloudapi.cn
    base_url=endpoints.endpoints.resource_manager)
```

but seems it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot, finally found the solution. Seems that no all the properties of Resource Manager Client are listed at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.resourcemanagementclient?view=azure-python

There is a property named credential_scopes which should be set for change

**credential_scopes=[CLOUD.endpoints.resource_manager + "/.default"])**

so the function looks like

```
def __init__(self, subscriptionId, resourceGroup):
  self.subscriptionId = subscriptionId
  self.resourceGroup = resourceGroup
  self.credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
  self.logger.info("Creating a client for deploying resources on subscription {}".format(self.subscriptionId))
  self.client = ResourceManagementClient(self.credentials, self.subscriptionId,
    base_url=CLOUD.endpoints.resource_manager,
    credential_scopes=[CLOUD.endpoints.resource_manager + "/.default"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
subscription_id = os.getenv("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID")
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id, base_url='https://management.chinacloudapi.cn', credential_scopes=["https://management.chinacloudapi.cn/.default"])

web_client = WebSiteManagementClient(credential, subscription_id, base_url='https://management.chinacloudapi.cn', credential_scopes=["https://management.chinacloudapi.cn/.default"])
```